# How to populate a Jlist

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a problem with `Jlist`. I want to make an DB select and put result string into a `Jlist`. My select is working, and i can view result in console, but how can I put it into my list?

```
...
private JList list;
...
final JList list = new JList();
list.setBounds(71, 111, 246, 79);
panelSelect.add(list);
...
try {
    connectionUtility.openConnection();

    String select = "SELECT ID_UN,NUME_UN,ADRESA_UN FROM UNIVER";

    connectionUtility.stm = connectionUtility.conn.prepareStatement(select);
    PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) connectionUtility.stm;

    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(select);

    while (rs.next()) {

        String univid = rs.getString("ID_UN");
        String univname = rs.getString("NUME_UN");
        String univadresse = rs.getString("ADRESA_UN");

        String label[] = {univid, univname, univadresse};

        //here I need to do something to put the elements into list                     
        // list.addItem ... ???

        //here I view selected data in console and works 100%
        System.out.println("univid : " + univid);
        System.out.println("univname : " + univname);
        System.out.println("univadresse : " + univadresse);

    }
```

Comment: when using JList you can construct it from a array or vector,you put the data in the array or vector;or implements a listmodel and add data to the model ,then notify JList to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) component has [setListData(Object[] ListData)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setListData%28E%5B%5D%29) method for set data of your jlist.
Now you can use this code in your program:

```
String [] ListData={univid , univname , univadresse};
YOUR_JLIST_NAME.setListData(ListData);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, with this code, I can obtain only one full row (just last univid , last univname and last univadresse) from my table. Can I obtain all rows in my Jlist?

Comment: yes with my code you can only set your list data, but if you want to dynamically add item to your list you should create [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) and set your JList with it.  like `DefaultListModel listmodel=new DefaultListModel();
        listmodel.addElement("YOUR NEW DATA"); 
        jList1.setModel(listmodel);`

Answer (score 2):

First, be careful because you have two JLists both called list:

```
...
private JList list; // This declares a first list
...
final JList list = new JList(); // This declares a second list
```

Then, you can do something like this;

```
....
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
list = new JList(listModel);
....
while (rs.next()) {
    String univname = rs.getString("NUME_UN");
    listModel.addElement(univname);
}
```